# Forward and delete all mails in a mailbox (linux)

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I've had some configuration issues with my postfix-mailserver. Apparently A LOT of messages have been sent from other mailservers, to my postmaster address.

I've already managed to redirect all future mails from root/postmaster to a mailbox I'm able to access externally.

Now, there are currently +3000 mails still in the 'root' mailbox.

How can I forward ALL these mails to a specific mailaddress? (Seperately; or as 1 big attachment doesn't matter)
And how can I delete ALL these mails at the same time?

I cannot seem to find the correct command within 'mail'.

Comment: On the server, can you just move all of the mail to the desired mailbox? They have already been delivered, they are out of postfix's control.

Comment: I'm using ZPanel to manage my other mailboxes, and I've followed your advise. I've been able to copy all of the mail to the 'new' folder of this mailbox, but these mails don't seem to appear in my mailclient.

My mailclient is setup correctly, because I can receive + send mails without any problems

When I open my webmail, there appears an item (No subject), but it's 0B big, so I think I'm doing something wrong here.

Comment: What IMAP-Server are you using.

Comment: I need this too. IMAP is no option, as I e.g. have no control over the destination mailbox. I just want to re-forward all mails in the mailbox to the address (because I broke the forwarding for quite a month now).

Comment: maybe https://serverfault.com/questions/773887/linux-forward-mail-in-mailbox is an option? But I don't get it.