# re-forward mails already IN mailbox using qmail

Tags: mailbox, mail-forwarding, qmail

I broke my qmail formwarding rule for quite a month, and incoming mails now are in my default mailbox instead of being forwarded to `&another|mail-adddress.com`. Is there a way to re-forward all mails in a qmail mailbox to an external address again? (no control over that IMAP mailbox, so imapsync etc won't work).

I saw [linux: forward mail in mailbox](https://serverfault.com/questions/773887/linux-forward-mail-in-mailbox), but I don't get it...

BTW: Using an Uberspace account.

Answer (score 0):

As always, I found the answer 5 minutes after putting the question on a stackexchange forum. Was googling half a day before without success...
If anyone needs it:

Open Mutt, select all Mails using `Shift`+`T` `.` `Enter` (just press these keys).
Then forward them using `;` `b` and entering the email to forward the mails.

This was the easiest solution I [found](https://contented.qolc.net/articles/using-mutt-on-linux-to-transfer-your-old-mbox-mail-folders-onto-gmail/).

I also posted that on [another question](https://serverfault.com/a/881235/200060)